# How to display objects of an array in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 4. I wanna display the contents of an array. According to docs, I have to use *ngFor directive to iterate and display the values. But I am unable to get any kind of results.

**Home.component.html:**

```
<h3 class="title">Top Restaurants near you</h3>
<div>
  <div class="card" *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">
    <span>{{restaurant._id}}</span>
    <span>{{restaurant.name}}</span>
  </div>
```

**Home.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestuarantService } from '../../services/restuarant.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  restaurant: Object;

  constructor(private router: Router, private restaurantService: RestuarantService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.restaurantService.getRestaurants().subscribe(restaurants => {
      console.log(restaurants.restaurants[0]);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });


  }

}
```

**Restaurant.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RestuarantService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getRestaurants() {
    let headers = new Headers;
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/restaurants', { headers: headers }).map(res => res.json());
  }

}
```

**Edit: 
Okay, So after a few struggle with this, and along with help of Sajeetharan, I am posting the solution.

Home.Component.TS should be like this:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RestuarantService } from '../../services/restuarant.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  restaurants: any = [];

  constructor(private router: Router, private restaurantService: RestuarantService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.restaurantService.getRestaurants().subscribe(restaurants => {
      this.restaurants = restaurants.restaurants[0];
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.restaurants));
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });


  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have **`restaurants`** variable declared and assign the response inside the **`subscribe`**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurants: any = [];
  constructor(private router: Router, private restaurantService: RestuarantService) { }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.restaurantService.getRestaurants().subscribe(restaurants => {
      this.restaurants = restaurants;
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this but I am unable to get any kind of response. Can you please explain why did you declare restaurants?

Comment: if you are using any variable in html it should be declared in the ts

Comment: what do you mean by not getting any kind of response?

Comment: I am unable to get any kind of output when I pass {{restaurant.name}}

Comment: can you do this inside subscribe and post the json here. console.log(JSON.stringify(this.restaurants));

Comment: It says undefined.